# Swift UItableView 8.4ver layout correct, 10.3ver is incorrect

Tags: swift, uitableview

I use the following code, Create UITableView programatically

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
       let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width+500
       self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: width, height:
       self.view.frame.height)
   }
```

8.4ver Layout:

[image: 8.4ver]

10.3ver Layout:

[image: 10.3ver]

Is it version bug? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The width you are specifying is 500 pts. more than the width of the screen, so that needs to be fixed.

Assuming you want the tableview to fill the screen, you should get the height from the same place you got the width.  This code works:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
       self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
       let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
       self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: width, height:
       UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 20)
   }
```